# Missing information in prominent disclosure

Tags: android, google-play

Recently, Google Play Console rejected my latest update and said that it is not compliant with the privacy policies. The email I received gave the reason: "Missing information in prominent disclosure".

I assume the "disclosure" refers the presented rationale I give in my app, to tell the user why I need their location.

Currently, that screen looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF637.jpg

Is it because the text needs to be improved? Or another reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've done several things, and some might be superfluous, but it worked:

navigate first to Play consolse -> App content -> Sensitive app permissions -> manage Policy compliance -> select yes

Main purpose:

> The app's main purpose is to [yada yada yada].

Location Access:

> The app need the access to the user's location so it can [yada yada yada].

Video instructions:

You have to make this yourself. Preferably one that shows a map or/and UI elements that utilise the location data.

More info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en-GB

if the use of the app requires a user, navigate to app content -> App Access -> "All or some functionality is restricted"

Fill in login info of a test user that you have created.
example:

> username: google@test.dk
>
> password: google1234

We also made a video of the onboarding flow to show that we notify the users of the location permission.

You then need to update the app and include a more comprehensive disclosure of location use. We use a full screen dialog (as opposed to simple pop up) in the onboarding flow to disclose what we use the location for. When the user click next, they are shown the available options, such as allow always/do not allow. The text we use is:

then navigate to App Content -> Privacy Policy

Copy and paste a URL to your privacy policy

This url should also be available from the location disclusure screen (such as "click here to read our privacy policy"), as well as available from the main app. In our app, we made this URL available in the settings page.

A general rule of thumb: you should  be completely and 100% transparent with what your app does with the data it uses.

Comment: "This url should also be available from the location disclusure screen (such as "click here to read our privacy policy"), as well as available from the main app." I don't see this direction anywhere mentioned by Google.

Comment: No, they don't mention a lot of stuff. I'm still not exactly sure if it's necessary, but we did it, and it got approved.

Answer (score 4):

You must have a look at the [prominent in-app disclosure](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en#zippy=%2Csee-an-example-of-prominent-in-app-disclosure%2Cstep-provide-prominent-in-app-disclosure) guides from Google.

Comment: They aren't helpful. They don't tell what exactly they want like "Show dialog for the user with explanation you are going to use this data" or something like this. However, if you implement it as you understand it, you may experience a long thread of discussion with google review team. The answer above is more straightforward and helpful.